# Hide div with javascript after page loads based on ASPxComboBox after page load from database from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#

I have an aspx page that contains an ASPxComboBox.  When this combo is changed after the page loads the div hides/unhides fine.  In my case I load existing values from the database.  I need to hide/show div based on these loaded values.  If I populate the dropdown with "None"  I want to hide the divs.  Thanks.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function OnSizeChanged(cbSide) {
    const str = cbSide.GetText().toString();
    if (str.includes('None')) {
      bottomtext.style.display = "block";
      lblbottomtext.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      lblbottomtext.style.display = "none";
      bottomtext.style.display = "none";
    }
  } 
  </script>
```

```html
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cbSide" runat="server" Width="280" ValueType="System.String">
  <Items>
    <dx:ListEditItem Text="DXF" Value="DXF" />
    <dx:ListEditItem Text="None" Value="None" />
  </Items>

  <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) { OnSizeChanged(s); }" />
  <ValidationSettings RequiredField-IsRequired="true" Display="Dynamic">
    <RequiredField IsRequired="True"></RequiredField>
  </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>

<div id="lblbottomtext" runat="server">
  <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblBST" runat="server" Text="Bottom Side Text:"></dx:ASPxLabel>
</div>
<div id="bottomtext" runat="server">
  <dx:ASPxMemo ID="txtBottom" runat="server" Height="71px" Width="280px"></dx:ASPxMemo>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the ASPxComboBox render as client side? Is it a text input with an associated unordered list or something else?

Comment: In this simple example it contains two items.    On page load I sometimes have a parameter on the url, ?OrderID=123.  Based on this I might load load "None" into the cbSide.  IN this case I want to hide the two divs above.  Thanks.